# Javascript merge values where they start with the same words

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I have:

```
var test ='1=Car&2=Bike&10=rabbit&10=dog&10=horse&11=ferrari&11=mercedes';
```

is a string, which I split and convert to array. I want that for every value that contains the same starting number, they get merged into the same value.

Example, the string above becomes tha array I don't want:

```
[ "1=Car", "2=Bike", "10=rabbit", "10=dog", "10=horse", "11=ferrari", "11=mercedes" ]
```

What I want, instead:

```
[ "1=Car", "2=Bike", "10=rabbit,dog,horse", "11=ferrari,mercedes" ]
```

My actual code:

```
var test ='1=Car&2=Bike&10=rabbit&10=dog&10=horse&11=ferrari&11=mercedes';
var array = test.split('&');
console.log(array);
var check_multiselect = null;
var current_multiselect = null;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
   var obj = value.split('=');
   if (obj[0] == check_multiselect) {
       console.log(current_multiselect);
       current_multiselect = key - 1;

       array[current_multiselect] = array[current_multiselect] +', '+obj[1];
   } 

   check_multiselect = obj[0];
};
console.log(array);
```

Which does not work as expected. What's wrong in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find same starting number and update the value.

```js
var test ='1=Car&2=Bike&10=rabbit&10=dog&10=horse&11=ferrari&11=mercedes',
    result = test
        .split('&')
        .reduce((r, string) => {
            let [key, value] = string.split('='),
                index = r.findIndex(q => q.split('=')[0] === key);

            if (index === -1) r.push(string);
            else r[index] += ',' + value;

            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```